# Admob Android Studio

Tags: android, admob

i am about to upload my new app to google play but i have problem when i add ads from `admob` the test ads appear correctly but when i use my real `adId` nothing appear ,even after more than 7 hours
note i tested in real device
please any help
the code is

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9402062085922389~9498102723");
        AdView adView=(AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and in **mainfast**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

**xml code**

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-9402062085922389/2082647133">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Have you added the payment options in Admob ? I also had similar issue but solved after adding payment options

Comment: @Anish thats right thing you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is one way you can get exact problem, you can implement the [Ad events](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)

The `onAdFailedToLoad()` method is the only one that includes a parameter. **The `errorCode` parameter indicates what type of failure occurred**. The possible values are defined as constants in the AdRequest class:

- ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR - Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.
- ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST - The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.
- ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR - The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.
- ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL - The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Comment: thinx for your answer the problem was with payment after I insert the information the ads appear